# Mapboxgl - points as a pie chart, no cluster

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl

trying to paint a circle as a pie chart based on the values in the properties.
Lets say I have an array on geojson features with this format:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-4.368, 0.85]
  },
  "properties": {
    "value1": 10,
    "value2": 5,
    "value3": 8
  }
}
```

I need to draw the point marker as a simple pie chart using the values in the properties. I don't find a way in the documentation for that. What I don't need is clustering, is for every single point in the map. I tried using 'circle-color' while adding the layer.

Is this possible? or any idea of how to acieve the same result but maybe using other features?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in Web by using SVGs. Here is a good example of how to do it: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/

But in case you want something similar in Android or iOS Mapbox apps there is nothing I could find. What I did for myself is a brute force approach by generating N permutation images for each case and using them depending on the case. E.g. if you have COLOR1, COLOR2, COLOR3, COLOR4 in you pie chart it will be 24 images that you need to have. Those images will not reflect exactly the percentage of each option but it could be something rough.

Another option that I want to explore for iOS and Android if it is possible to generate PieChart image/svg on the fly and use it. But from what I remember it is not trivial for iOS and Android.